# Remove single quotes on number notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi i have one file with 3600+ line and different numbers in single quotes and i want to remove single quotes 
ex.

> '1438115887'
>     '192'
>     '143854321'
>     '17'
>     '321122'

This is full line

```
(27, 'user', 'demo@demo.com', '', '', 1, 0, 'Europe/London', 1, 2, '', 2, 6, '61', 0, '1424716755', '1437805182', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 'valid', 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1),
```

Can i remove `' '` from all number?
I try with `^\d+` but not effect.

Thank you

Comment: So you just want the quotes removed from around the numbers, but not anything containing letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Find and Replace with two regular expressions:

1. find: `'(.\d)`  replace: `\1`
2. find: `(.\d)'` replace: `\1`

It might not work if the email starts with digit.

Edit:

Better solution in one Find and replace:
Find: `'(.\d+)'`  and replace: `\1`

Comment: Work with this `'(.\d+)'` Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think find and replace should work perfectly. Just find `'` and replace it with nothing.